# Retrieve data from selected list element in Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm new to the whole coding thing and have been learning a lot with yer help lately so I hope it may continue with the next problem I am having!

I have a Jquery list which is rendering perfectly and what it does is display some dummy info I've inputted that comes from a local MYSQL database. What I've done so far is that when the user clicks on one of the listed links it will bring them to the next page and say "You have selected link #" and the # tag in this instance represents the dealid number of the users selected list link.

What I'm trying to find out what to do is this:

1. With the information I've gained from the users selection (i.e. the selected dealid number) how can I then pass this back onto the database so I can find and retrieve the particular entry with that dealid number.

My HTML code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Find A Deal</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <style>
        img.fullscreen {
            max-height: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
        }
        </style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){
        $("#list").empty();
        var url="http://localhost/test/json3.php";
        $.getJSON(url,function(json){
            //loop through deals
            $.each(json.deals,function(i,dat){
                $("#list").append("<li><a id='"+dat.dealid+"'><h1>"+dat.name+"</h1><p>"+dat.dname+"</p></a></li>");
                $(document).on('click', '#'+dat.dealid, function(event){  
                    if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
                    {
                        listObject.itemID = $(this).attr('id'); 
                        $.mobile.changePage( "#index2", { transition: "slide"} );
                        event.handled = true;
                    }
                });            
            });
            $("#list").listview('refresh');
        });
    });

    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index2', function(){       
    $('#index2 [data-role="content"]').html('You have selected Link' + listObject.itemID);
//  var url="http://localhost/test/json9.php";
//  $.getJSON(url, function(json){






    });

    var listObject = {
        itemID : null
    }    
</script>
</head>     
<body>    
<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Current Deals</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="content-primary">
            <ul id="list" data-role="listview" data-filter="true"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://localhost/findadeal/index.html" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://localhost/findadeal/mydeal.html" data-icon="grid">My Deals</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--New Page --> 

<div data-role="page" id="index2">
<div data-role="header">
        <h1> Find A Deal </h1> 
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <a data-role="button" href="#page1" data-icon="star" data-iconpos="left">Get Deal </a>
    </div>

    <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <nav data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#index" data-icon="grid">My Deals</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </footer>   
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The PHP/Json file that is being referenced to create the original list (Json3.php) is as follows:

```
<?php

$link = mysql_pconnect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Could not Connect to DB");

mysql_select_db("findadeal") or die("Could not select database");

$arr = array();

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT r.restaurantid, r.name, r.image, d.dealid, d.dname, d.restaurantid
FROM restaurant r, deal d
WHERE r.restaurantid = d.restaurantid;");

while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
$arr[] = $obj;
}

echo '{"deals":'.json_encode($arr).'}';

?>
```

I'm running at a loss here as I've been looking for information on this for a while and cant seem to find what I'm looking for. I appreciate anyones help, I really mean it! Thanks in advance!! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can simplify your javascript like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#'+dat.dealid, function(event){  
    listObject.itemID = $(this).attr('id'); 
    $.mobile.changePage( "#index2", { transition: "slide"} );
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

If you want to load the data of your item without reloading the page then you need to do an ajax request. If you don't mind reloading the page, redirect to `http://domain.com/uri/whatever?id=<the_selected_id>` then in your PHP script you can get the item using the get parameter `$_GET['id']` and perform a query to get the data for this id.

**UPDATE**

You need a PHP script to retrieve the data from the database. This script is called like this: `http://www.domain.com/foo/bar/my_script.php?id=<the_id_from_the_selection>`

And your script should looks like this:

```
<?php

// Default value to return
$data = array('error' => 'No deal found');

if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {

    // Using PDO for the database connection, it's much better and avoid SQL injection
    // Make sure the PDO extension is enable in your php.ini
    $pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=<SOMEDB>', '<USERNAME>', 'PASSWORD');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM deal WHERE id = :id";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute(array('id' => $_GET['id']));
    $data = $statement->fetch(\PDO:FETCH_ASSOC);
}

echo json_encode($data);

// You don't need the closing PHP tag. Actually it's easier to debug if you don't use it.
```

Your ajax request (called when user select something, this is javascript) should look like this:

```
var dealId; // the selected deal id

$.ajax({
  url : 'foo/bar/my_script.php',
  data: {id: dealId},
  type: "GET",
  async: true,
  onSuccess: function(response){
     console.log(response); // look into the console to check the object structure
     // Display your data here using dom selector and jquery
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the quick comment back! Sounds good, I'll have to do a bit of reading up about the 2 of them methods first before figuring out how to do them. Have you any idea what the second method you suggested is called? Or which of the 2 would you personally recommend? Cause I feel not reloading the page would make the app seem better but I'm not sure what industry standard would be!

Comment: If you need to display the data on the same page the drop-down select you better use ajax. For that I'd recommend jQuery $.ajax(). You'll need to call a php script to get the data from the database and return it (as a json string, look at PHP `json_encode()`). If you look for $.ajax() tutoriel you'll find what you want

Comment: Drop Down Select? Is that a type of list or something?

The list I'm using is just a standard one. The different elements are listed on a full page when the user navigates to that certain page. Then when the selection is made they're brought to a new page where I want the new information to be displayed - would I still be using that $.ajax for that yes?

Comment: if you are redirecting to a new page, no, you don't need ajax. But can't see the redirect in your exemple.

Comment: My apologies, I hope I'm not causing confusion. 

When the id of the clicked element is being displayed it is being rendered on index2 - the code of which is called at the end of the html file I have above. And this goes across just fine! The reason I was rendering that number on index2 was just a test to see if the correct thing was being selected :)

What I'm having trouble figuring out is how do I send that dealid to the database so I can pull just that record across and display it on the index2 page.